# Someone doesn't like an edit I suggested, and downvotes all of my questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, suggested-edits, down-votes

I am new to StackOverflow, and I edited few posts based on how I had seen many posts being written and one 'celeb' person here pointed out where I was wrong. I thanked him for letting me know, and that I was doing what I saw in good posts. But, I got downvotes on all my questions at the same time.

I don't think it
s fair. (Not saying it because I lost reputation.) It just decreases credibility of my questions to anyone who sees it. This, to me, is just having advantage of being someone with high reputation and they can just go downvoting anyone because -1 reputation won't matter to them.

Comment: Oh and FYI, there is no -1 rep penalty to downvote a question, that is only for answers.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for your comments, I will check that post.

Comment: While not an excuse for serial downvoting, you have made a number of suggested edits that abuse code formatting for emphasis, which is widely considered an extremely obnoxious practice. So you may be opening yourself to targeting because of that.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Yeah, as I said I was unaware, and I was suggesting edits based on what I had seen in several posts.

Comment: someone has flu it's a duplicate ?? wtf every situation is different where else this user will clear his/her doubts ??How can you say it's a duplicate ??what is the advantage of marking this question as `duplicate` by d way ?

Comment: @Suraj All the OP needs to know is explained in the duplicate, that's why it's marked as such

Comment: @slhck thanks for your reply , what i want to say is what is the scope of duplicate ? How you define duplicate , I think if i am not wrong Meta is a place for asking such questions only and every user has different experience so why mark `Duplicate` in `META` , I perfectly understand in `stackoverflow` , technical questions can be duplicate and OP should have searched enough before asking question , But in `META` it's not about technical questions .

Comment: @Suraj There is no difference whether it's technical or not. The user has a question, and when their question is answered by another question's answers, it'll be marked as a duplicate. We do this to prevent all the information from being scattered across the site. Just like on Stack Overflow – for topics that are asked a lot (like serial voting, question banning, etc.) there should be *one* canonical question we can point users to. Not a new question every day with the same answers. *That* is the reason for duplicates – the principle is the same here on Meta just like on any other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relax. It'll be reversed in around 24 hours. If it will repeat, downvoter will be warned and mods will take care. If nothing happens in 24 hours, flag one of your downvoted questions for attention and explain there what you think happened.

Comment: That is, as long as they downvote more than 3 questions/answers.  Seems like hitting 3 at a time, several days in a row, keeps you under the radar.

Comment: @JohnnyBones he got 5 downvoted today, and that are old questions that would probably earn honest downvotes long time ago, if anything. I bet it will kick in.

Comment: @JohnnyBones The algorithm for determining serial voting is more complex than just determining if there is more or less than three in a day.  There are quite a few factors that are all taken into consideration.

Comment: @Mołot - I got hit on SE on the 9th, and they never got reversed.  And they were all old questions too.  Looked to me like groups of 3's.  Just seemed a bit "fishy" to me.

Comment: @Mołot It never got reversed through that serial down-voting ..